# error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server - only on production server

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, web-config

When I try to connect a remote database on local machine it connects, but when I try to do so on the host sometimes I get

> Error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server

I checked: SQL Server and it allows remote connections. I could not find the source of error.

Thanks in advance.

Error detail:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Comment: Can you ping the hostname to start with? Do you use IP or hostname to connect. Try by IP. Is the port open on that host? I would start troubleshooting from there. Then check if SQL server allows incoming remote connections.

Comment: network or dns issues are two possibilities. There's just no generic answer to this question. Unless you can track down a clue, change your code to cope is something you should look at.